# Re-direct error message to logfile in bash

Tags: bash, shell

[Editing, as the question posted was wrong]
I need to save the output of this code in a file named 'logfile' and have only the error in calculations in that logfile.

```
for f in *.log; do 
awk 'NF && NR>1 && $0!~/total:/
{
things_cost=$2*$3; 
overalltotal=(overalltotal!="")? overalltotal"+"things_cost : things_cost; 
if(things_cost!=$4)
{ 
things_er[$1]=things_cost" instead of "$4 
}
err_t+=$4; t+=things_cost;
}
$0~/total/ && err_t 
{ 
print "Error in calculations:"; 
for(i in things_er) 
{ 
print "Things total for "i" is wrong: it should be "things_er[i] 
} 
print "Overalltotal is wrong: It should be "t; next 
}1' "$f" tmpfile && mv tmpfile logfile
done
```

Using the above code, the errors are repeating in the logfile and in a very unreadable format. I am using the input file given below. I need the date and the errors to be printed in the logfile

```
Date: 01-01-2007
    Sold     price    total
thing1   3    7098    22394
thing2    2    6500    13000
thing3   20    300    6000
Overalltotal: 41394
-----------------------------------
Date: 04-01-2007
    Sold     price    total
thing1    10    700    5000
thing2  48    900    43200
Overalltotal: 46020
```

---

Comment: Are you sure there is an error? The error.log file will only be populated if the command the return code from the awk command is greater than 0.

Comment: I am trying to print the error in calculations of input file to a logfile. When i tried directly re-directing the output of this 'for' loop to a 'logfile' it did not work.

Comment: Unset variables default to 0; you can simply write `overalltotal += things_cost` without the conditional.

Comment: There's no `exit` command in awk, so it will (probably) always succeed, so you are goint to execute `mv tmpfile logfile` on every iteration of the loop.  That seems pretty pointless.

Answer (score -1):

Your awk code is not outputting anything to stderr, I guess that you want to have outputs on both stderr and stdout. To do so you have to do the following

```
(echo "test" | awk '{print $0; print $0." error" | "cat 1>&2" }') > log 2> err_log
```

The important part here is the `| "cat 1>&2"` that you have to append after every error print that you do. At the end of your awk command you have to redirect stdout to a `log` file and stderr to an `err_log` file using `>`and `2>`.

---

Here is how it works:

```
echo "\
#################################
Date: 01-01-2007
thing1   3    7098    22394
thing2    2    6500    13000
thing3   20    300    6000
--------------------------------
Date: 04-01-2007
thing4    10    700    5000
thing5  48    900    43200
Overalltotal: 46020
#################################
total 89593" > test.csv

(awk '
    !/^#/ && !/^total/ && $2~/[0-9]+/ && $3~/[0-9]+/ && $4~/[0-9]+/ {
        line_cost = $2*$3
        real_total += line_cost;
        precomputed_total += $4; 
        if(line_cost!=$4)
            errors[NR]="Error (product "$1": line " NR ") line cost is " line_cost" != " $4;
        print "\t"$0;
    }
    /^total/ && length(errors)>0 { 
        print "\tErrors in item totals:" | "cat 1>&2";
        for(i in errors)  
            print "\t\t"errors[i] | "cat 1>&2"; 
        if (real_total != precomputed_total)
        print "\tPre-computed total: "$2 | "cat 1>&2";
        print "\tOverall total based on items totals: "precomputed_total | "cat 1>&2";
        print "\tOverall total based on items price*quantity: "real_total | "cat 1>&2";
    }' test.csv) > log 2> err_log

echo "Content of log file"
cat log
echo "Content of err_log file"
cat err_log
```

Outputs the following:

```
Log:
    thing1   3    7098    22394
    thing2    2    6500    13000
    thing3   20    300    6000
    thing4    10    700    5000
    thing5  48    900    43200
Error log:
    Errors in item totals:
        Error (product thing1: line 3) line cost is 21294 != 22394
        Error (product thing4: line 8) line cost is 7000 != 5000
    Pre-computed total: 89593
    Overall total based on items totals: 89594
    Overall total based on items price*quantity: 90494
```

Comment: I wanted to have the output re-directed to a file. Have edited the question, i need to print the errors to the file.

Comment: I don't get what you need then. Cause the code I gave here does redirect the output to a file and the error output to another. 

You just need to do two things, modify your prints inside awk script to:
`print "Error in calculations:" | "cat 1>&2";`

And then add at the end of your awk call, two redirections, one for stdout, ie., `> whateverlogfile` and another for stderr, ie., `2> whatevererrorlog`.

Comment: It is not stderr, it's just error in the calculations in the input file. If you look at the input file, in the total cost of thing1 is 21294(7098 * 3), whereas it is mentioned 22394. So my log file will have :

Error in calculations:Error in calculations:

Things total for thing1 is wrong: it should be 21294 instead of 22394
Overalltotal is wrong: It should be 40294

Comment: I think you are missing something in what I posted. The solution to your problem probably is to write things to stderr (error in calculations), and some others to stdout (eg., `thing1   3    7098    22394`). If you do so, then its very easy to output errors to a log and non error to your terminal, or to an other file.